# Column is of type bytea but expression is of type record

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am attempting to replace html content with PostgreSQL. The html lives within a "contents" column that exists in a messagetemplates table. I keep getting this error: column "contents" is of type bytea but expression is of type record; HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. I know this is because the return types are different. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I can accomplish casting the expression.

Here is my code:

```
update org0000008.messagetemplates
set contents = replace (contents, 'Your password is: [%= :xd_paid_pass_wd %]', '<a href="https://moneymappress.com/reset-password/">Click here to reset your password</a>')
where contents in 
(
    SELECT mt.contents
    FROM org0000008.mailings m INNER JOIN maincontrol.orgs o ON o.orgid = 
    m.orgid 
    INNER JOIN org0000008.segments s 
    ON s.mailingid = m.mailingid 
    INNER JOIN org0000008.messagetemplates mt 
    ON s.messagetemplateid = mt.messagetemplateid 
    WHERE TRUE
    AND (
    m.startdate >= '2018-06-01'
    OR m.createddate >= '2018-06-01'
    ) 
    AND (
    contents LIKE '%Your password is: [%= :xd_paid_pass_wd %]%'
    )
    and m.mailingid = 788733

    )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The built-in `replace` function does not accept bytea. Either you have your own `replace` function or `org0000008.messagetemplates.contents` is not a bytea field. Please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I ran the following: `SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = 'messagetemplates' AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'contents'` and it returned a data type of bytea. What do you mean by "Either you have your own replace function?" IS there an alternative to using replace?

Comment: Can you issue `\df replace` when logged to your db with `psql` and add the result to your question?